# Best method to remove managed child lists. One-to-many / parent-child relationships

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I have 2 managed objects in my database that look like this.

```
public class Product : RealmObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public RealmList<Report> Reports { get; } // child objects
}
```

and

```
public class Report : RealmObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public Product Parent { get; set; } // Parent object reference
}
```

Each time my app is loaded a web hit fetches a list of Products and then starts managing them in a Realm database, it displays the Products in a TableView. When you click one of the products in the table view, you get a list of Reports. The list of reports is fetched by another web hit using the product id. Every time I get a new list of reports from the web I need to remove all the old Report objects from the Realm database that are linked to one specific product (by id).

Herein lies the confusion. According to this https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#current-limitations cascading deletes is currently not supported. I assume that means deleted objects in a relationship like I have above. So for the time being what is the best approach to remove the child objects (RealmList) without breaking things. I have come up with 2 approaches so far. Here's some code.

**Approach A**:

```
// id is passed in as a param by function 
var reportsById = realm.All<Report>.Where(r => r.Product.Id == id).ToList();

foreach (var report in reportsById)
{
    // Delete an object with a transaction
    using (var trans = realm.BeginWrite()) 
    {
        realm.Remove(report);
        trans.Commit();
    }
}

// Then simply add the new reports to my old Product 
// Pseudo code
var newreports = getnewreports()
foreach report in newreports
   product.Reports.add(report)
```

**Approach B:**

```
// Get the current Product object
var currentProduct = realm.All<Product>.Where(p => p.Id == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var report in currentProduct.Reports)
{
    // Delete an object with a transaction
    using (var trans = realm.BeginWrite()) 
    {
        realm.Remove(report);
        trans.Commit();
    }
}

// Add new reports to product again
```

And finally this is the approach I used to add my child objects (reports from the web) to the parent (product).

```
// First
var webReports = await FetchWebReport(); // IList<Report> type

/...../

// Then
var currentProduct = Realm.blah()... // get from realm database with query

foreach (var report in webReports)
{
    // Manage object with a transaction
    using (var trans = realm.BeginWrite()) 
    {
        // Add reference to parent product
        report.Parent = currentProduct;

        // Add to child list in product
        currentProduct.Reports.Add(report);

        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Has anybody got any ideas/input? Feel free to to pick apart my current code. Point out issues. Thanks Realm Devs. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official Realm answer - you were nearly right with B ;-)

Note the following sample uses the `Write(lambda)` style rather than explicit transaction creation and commit. It's a bit more concise but doing the same work.

I'm also looping *inside* the transaction rather than doing many transactions. It's faster and means the collection of related updates are in a single transaction.

**create some sample hierarchies**

```
realm.Write (() => {
    for (var pid = 1; pid <= 4; ++pid) {
        var p = realm.CreateObject<Product>();
        p.Id = pid; 
        p.Name = $"Product {pid}";
        for (var rid = 1; rid <= 5; ++rid) {
            var r = realm.CreateObject<Report>();
            r.Id = rid+pid*1000; 
            r.Ref = $"Report {pid}:{rid}";
            p.Reports.Add(r);  // child object added to relationship
        }
    }
});
```

**Do the delete**

Find an object we want to do a psuedo-cascading delete on - I'm directly using the LINQ `First` to get the object.

```
var delId = 1;
var delP = realm.All<Product>().First(p => p.Id == delId);  
if (delP == null)
  return;
```

**Important fix to your sample - use** `ToList`

```
realm.Write(() => {
    foreach (var r in delP.Reports.ToList())  
        realm.Remove(r); 
    realm.Remove(delP);  // lastly remove the parent 
});
```

Your approach in B was nearly correct **but** it ignores the fact that `foreach (var report in currentProduct.Reports)` is iterating a **live list.** Because the `Reports` container is updated each time you remove something, it will exit the loop before removing all the children.

Comment: You're welcome. Normally we are busy telling people they *don't* have to use `ToList`. This is a rare exception ;-)

Comment: Haha interesting don't suppose you can tell me about that or link me to a post with it? I use ToList all the time.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using ToList in most .NET code. However, it does generate a container in memory. The RealmResults class is a live container which is updated when you change objects in other threads. It is also _lazy_ and objects are only created as you enumerate the results. The lazy aspect doesn't matter if you just have a few dozen objects but if you had results of thousands of objects and called ToList, there could be a notable hit in time and heap activity. https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/0.76.0/api/class_realms_1_1_realm_results.html